# What does this symbol mean. Transformer with a Z in it

Tags: transformer

I'm trying to figure out what kind of transformer this is. It's part of an AC to DC converter.

It's a symbol of a transformer with a Z between the two windings.

[image]

Comment: Hi, please check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/407633/common-mode-choke-symbol-and-orientation, the LCM, i believe, stands for L Common Mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a transformer.

It is two magnetically coupled inductors, i.e. a common-mode choke.

Comment: A transformer *is* a perfect description of it; it's just being used sideways to a power transformer (e.g., think of it as a 1:1 current transformer). Note that the "inductors" are never rated for saturation current (or if they are, it's extremely small).  (Mind I'm here using '"inductor"' in the commercial sense i.e. a component sold for energy storage purposes, with rated inductance, Q and Isat; and "transformer" in the sense of a power transfer component intended to store minimal energy.)